# mysql query for check multiple not empty column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm want to check multiple not empty columns, something like I did for check multiple empty columns:-

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE "" IN(`profilepic2`,`bsector`,`gender`,`first_name`,`sur_name`,`phone`,`hphone`,`countryresd`,`passportnum`,`maritalstatus`,`haddress`,`countryofbus`,`maddress`,`paddress`)
```

Now I want not empty columns through mysql query.

Comment: WHERE "" ?. "" is a column name?

Comment: what about `WHERE '' NOT IN`...

Comment: strange ' ' NOT IN working . great !!!

Answer (score 1):

This should be worked.Replace `some_col` with your required column.

```
 SELECT * FROM users WHERE some_col IS NULL OR some_col = " ";
```

Comment: IS NULL not checking empty columns

Comment: Then use `"" NOT IN` for checking.Hope it can be helped.

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM users WHERE  some_col != "" AND some_col IS NOT NULL;

Comment: this method not support multiple column, that can only check single column

Answer (score 0):

```
$fields = mysql_query("SHOW columns FROM mytablename");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($fields))
{$field_name[] = $row['Field'];
}
for($i=0; $i<sizeof($field_name; $i++;)){`enter code here`
"SELECT * FROM users WHERE '".$field_name[$i]."' IS NULL OR '".$field_name[$i]."' = ''";
}
```